# How to remove extra SS from datetime format python

Tags: python

I have this date format returned from a db table : `'2020-05-08 12:25:39.837597'`

Query :

```
select max(dateSt) from tableX
```

Table format :

```
dateSt = Timestamp(6)
```

Is there a way to have only the first two digits from mm in python 3.X?

`'2020-05-08 12:25:39.83'`

EDIT:

The value is stored in a list, datatype is datetime for the specific value.

Comment: Of course there are possible ways. Which type does your column have? String? Timestamp?

Comment: Timestamp(6), but i just need it to satisfy this format `'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'`, that's why I need to get rid of the extra mm.

Comment: How did you get `'2020-05-08 12:25:39.837597'` in the first place?

Comment: String-based: `date[0:-4]`

Comment: Selected it from a databse with `select column_name form table_X`, the column type is timestamp(6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a way to do it, so i just removed all the microseconds :

```
d = datetime.datetime.replace(microsecond=0)
```